# How can I get API client? (Google Play Services)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services, google-api-client

I am trying to do online rating and achivments in my app, used google play services. I do it at first time and I can't understand how it must be in code.

```
Games.Achievements.unlock(client, "CgkI2qWM-fIQEAIQAQ");
Games.Achievements.increment(client, "CgkI2qWM-fIQEAIQAQ", 1);
```

So, my question. How can i get Api client?

I'm trying with this code, from docs. But get an error.

```
client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
        .setAccountName("myMail@gmail.com")
        .build();
        client.connect();
```

My logs

```
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410): java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hn.a(Unknown Source)
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.b(Unknown Source)
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410):    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.AchievementsImpl.unlock(Unknown Source)
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410):    at com.pahanuch.candiesmaster.Main.Save(Main.java:1926)
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410):    at com.pahanuch.candiesmaster.Main$4.run(Main.java:1912)
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-05 10:25:49.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14410):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google recommends using the [BaseGameUtils](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples) for managing Play Games services. This automatically takes care of most of the hard work (such as sign-in, unlocking achievements, etc) and is a much easier and safer way to interact with the Play Games service.

Have a look at [this article](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin) which describes how to use the `BaseGameUtils` for sign-in, and then read subsequent ones for achievements, etc. All the information is provided there for you to get started quickly.

NOTE: `BaseGameUtils` is provided in the `android-samples` package. It can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples) - look inside `/BasicSamples/libraries` to find it.

Answer (score 1):

connection is asynchronous. the `GoogleApiClient` will execute a callback when it has connected or, more likely the first time, failed to connect and requires further action.

review the documentation for how to implement `onConnectionFailed()`, `onConnectionSuspended()`, and `onConnected()`. you can only use the `GoogleApiClient` when you have received an `onConnected()` callback without a corresponding `onConnectionSuspended()` callback.